# Entity Framework DbContext load performance

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following model classes and associated DbContext object.

```
public class PlayerModel
{
    [Key]
    public string PlayerID { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Player")]
    public virtual ICollection<SeasonStats> SeasonStats { get; set; }

    //General
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }

    public PlayerModel()
    {
        this.SeasonStats = new List<SeasonStats>();
    }

}

public class PlayerModelDBContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<PlayerModel> Players { get; set; }
}
```

I am attempting to populate a View with the first 20 entries of about 7500 from the database.

```
public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Players.Take(20));
    }
```

The request is timing out as I expect it is taking too long to populate the DbContext.  How can I configure the context to only fetch records from the DB when requested?

Comment: Have you tried to return `View(db.Players.AsQueryable().Take(20))`? As far as I know this method is to optimalizing queries sending to database.

Comment: A request of 7500 entries shouldn't be timing out. But even then, your code is doing exactly what you want it to do.

Comment: I should clarify: setting properties as virtual means that they will be lazy loaded, i.e. only when needed.

Comment: There is apparently something wrong elsewhere. 7500 entries would load, not to mention just top 20 of them. My guess is that your view is doing something nasty with the resultset.

Comment: You _expect_ it to time-out, but does it really? Try to verify it by using an EF Profiler. Or you could just debug it, try and see if `db.Players.Take(20).ToList()` really takes that long.

Comment: The code that you have shown looks fine, your error is most likely somewhere else.

Comment: Try return View(db.Players.Take(20).ToList()); in case your view is doing something wrong.

Comment: It should not be a problem here but what's the point in the virtual keyword here: public virtual DbSet<PlayerModel> Players { get; set; }?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was able to figure it out, as it turns out the db had not yet fully populated, even though I had stopped the debugger there was still a background process filling the database.